# stop an event upon mouseup fired by mousedown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have searched a lot but i could not find any solution for this or may be i was unable to find good keywords for the question.
I am working on an audio player and the problem is volume control.
Here is my code the dragging function should only occur when mousedown function is working otherwise it should not work , but it does not disable onmousemove event on leaving the mouse button so i need your help..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".volume_wrapper_slider").on("mousedown", function(e) {
        $(this).on("mousemove", function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
            var slider_width = $(this).width();
                    var slider_offset = $(this).offset().left;
                    var percentage1 = (100 / slider_width);
                    var current_percentage = percentage1 * (e.clientX-slider_offset);           
                        // move the bar w.r.t click
                    $(".vol_slided").width(current_percentage+"%");
                    now_playing.volume = parseFloat(percentage1 * ($(".vol_slided").width()/100));
        });
    });
            // mouse up
    $(".volume_wrapper_slider").mouseup(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Update -----------------------------

this solved my problem thanks to @jaromanda-x

```
        // volume control

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".volume_wrapper_slider").on("mousedown", function(e) {
            canDrag = true;
            $(this).on("mousemove", function(e) {
               if (canDrag == true) {
                 var slider_width = $(this).width();
                        var slider_offset = $(this).offset().left;
                        var percentage1 = (100 / slider_width);
                        var current_percentage = percentage1 * (e.clientX-slider_offset);

                            // move the bar w.r.t click
                        $(".vol_slided").width(current_percentage+"%");
                        now_playing.volume = parseFloat(percentage1 * ($(".vol_slided").width()/100));
               } 

            });
                // mouse up
        $(".volume_wrapper_slider").mouseup(function(e) {
            canDrag = false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what event are you trying to stop? have you try using `.off()`?

Comment: you want to set isDragging true on mousedown, and isDragging false on mouseup and only process move events if isDragging is true ... basically, there's probably more you need to worry about if the mouse is released outside of the element in question

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX , let me try

Comment: @AneesIjaz you should add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that worked for me..

```
        // volume control

$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".volume_wrapper_slider").on("mousedown", function(e) {
            canDrag = true;
            $(this).on("mousemove", function(e) {
               if (canDrag == true) {
                 var slider_width = $(this).width();
                        var slider_offset = $(this).offset().left;
                        var percentage1 = (100 / slider_width);
                        var current_percentage = percentage1 * (e.clientX-slider_offset);

                            // move the bar w.r.t click
                        $(".vol_slided").width(current_percentage+"%");
                        now_playing.volume = parseFloat(percentage1 * ($(".vol_slided").width()/100));
               } 

            });
                // mouse up
        $(".volume_wrapper_slider").mouseup(function(e) {
            canDrag = false;
        });
    });
});
```